# When does this "primes" matrix have full row and column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, prime-numbers, intuition, matrix-equations

When does the following type of matrix have full row and column rank?

For each entry, we take the value $v$=row*column.
Then for the $b$th bit of $v$, $v_b$ we take the $b$th prime to the $v_b$ power.

**EXAMPLES**

Say row = 5 and column = 7.
This is 5*7=35, which, in binary, is $100011_2$
So we take
$$\cdot 13^1 \cdot 11^0 \cdot 7^0 \cdot 5^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 2^1$$ 
$$=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 13$$
$$=78$$
...So the entry for the 5th row and 7th column would be 78.

Say row = 4 and column = 2.
This is 4*2=8, which, in binary, is $001000_2$
So we take
$$\cdot 13^0 \cdot 11^0 \cdot 7^1 \cdot 5^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 2^0$$ 
$$=7$$
...So the entry for the 4th row and 2nd column would be 7.

**THE GENERAL MATRIX**

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^0 3^0 5^0  &  \dots\\
        2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^1 3^0 5^0  &  2^0 3^1 5^0  &  2^1 3^1 5^0  &  2^0 3^0 5^1  &  \dots\\
        2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^0 3^1 5^0  &  2^0 3^0 5^1  &  2^0 3^1 5^1  &  2^0 3^0 5^0 7^1  &  \dots\\
        2^0 3^0 5^0  &  2^1 3^1 5^0  &  2^1 3^1 5^0  &  2^1 3^0 5^0 7^1  &  2^0 3^0 5^1 7^1  &  \dots\\
        \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots\\
 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

We can assume that the matrix is an $N \times N$ matrix.

**SOME OBSERVATIONS**

Just a general observation:  The only counterexample for $N \times N$ matrices with $N$ ranging from 2 to 20 is $N=3$.  All other matrices have full rank.

Comment: Just to be sure, the left column and the top row have index $0$, haven't they?

Comment: Managed to google this: if the determinant is nonzero, the matrix is invertible, and invertible matrices have full rank. So try writing the expression of the determinant?

Comment: @ajotatxe:  Yes, they're indexed starting at 0.  Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: @Emil:  That's a good possibility.  It might be really hard to find a way to calculate the determinant, though.  I'll give it a try to see if I can find an easy solution, so thanks!

Comment: I got the determinant of the 3x3 matrix to be zero. So I think you need to keep hunting for matrices.

Comment: @Emil:  You're right...  But I noticed that the 4x4 matrix and the 11x11 matrix have full row and column rank, via Mathematica.  Maybe only a subset of $N \times N$ matrices have this property...  I really need to know which ones do...

Comment: I would describe the determinant for matrices as a sum over products of row-connected paths through it (each column can only be visited once), weighted according to the signature of the permutation  of the path (there is some nifty way to compute that too but I have forgotten it at the moment. I think it is related to the number of times the path "jumps back" in the columns. look up inversions and parity of a permutation on wikipedia). So pondering over the determinant definitions that exist might give hints on designing such matrices.

Comment: Ok in my interpretation after an element is visited it starts to complain "inversion!" each time the path is left of it (even if it is longer down in the matrix). Then the sum of all complaints is the number of inversions. (-1)^(#inversions)=signature of permutation. (I hope this is correct, because it sounded fun in my head. they yelled "noo" instead but anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Easy counterexample, take $N = 3$ and you will see that it is not full ranked:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2^03^05^0=1 & 2^03^05^0=1 & 2^03^05^0=1 \\
2^03^05^0=1 & 2^13^05^0=2 & 2^03^15^0=3 \\
2^03^05^0=1 & 2^03^15^0=3 & 2^03^05^1=5 \end{array} \right)$, this matrix is not full rank, so your question's answer would be no, it is not always full rank.